# In JS map() method, why can't callback function parameters compute with each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array.prototype.map

The problem is that I cannot subtract each index of an array from its element(number), using the array.prototype.map() method. I expected the subtraction to be valid, but it is not.

Here is the code:

```
const whiteSp = [ 5, 11 ];
whiteSp.map(function (ele, i) {
        console.log(ele, i) // 5 0, 11 1
        console.log(ele - i) // 5, 10
        ele = ele - i;
         return ele;
    });
    console.log(whiteSp) // expected [ 5, 10 ], but got [ 5, 11 ]
```

The second console.log indicates the computation has been made as seen by the value 10, but returns 11 for some reason.

I have also tried `'return ele - i'` without its above line, but still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, you could try something like this:

```js
let whiteSp = [ 5, 11 ];
whiteSp = whiteSp.map((ele, i) => { return ele - i; });
console.log(whiteSp)
```

and remember that `map` function returns a new array so you have to do `whiteSp = whiteSp.map...`.

Comment: `(ele, i) => { return ele - i; }` === `(ele, i) => ele - i`

Comment: As you prefer. I prefer to use `return` statement. It hepls me to understand faster what I'm doing in `map`. Of course this is a small example but in general I write something more complex in `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

You need an assignment of the mapped values.

```js
const
    whiteSp = [5, 11],
    result = whiteSp.map((ele, i) => ele - i);

console.log(result);
```